# Receiving a NullReference Exception error during HttpPost Action when using a ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to create what I feel is a very simple form submission using a ViewModel.  I have worked on this off and on all day and for some reason cannot understand why when my app gets to my HttpPost action my EmailViewModel is empty.  I get a "NullReference Exception Occurred" "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

Can you take a look at my code and tell me where I am being crazy?

Here is my httpPost action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendStudentAnEmail(EmailViewModel email)
{
        Debug.Write(email.Subject); // First NullReferenceException
        Debug.Write(email.Body);
        Debug.Write(email.Email);
        etc. . .
```

My ViewModel:

```
namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    public class EmailViewModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Subject { get; set; }

        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and My View:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.EmailViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SendStudentAnEmail";
}

<h2>SendStudentAnEmail</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>EmailViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subject)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subject)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Body)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Body)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Thank you.

*UPDATE*

If I change my HttpPost Action to use FormCollection, I can use the values just fine, I can even re-cast the FormCollection values back to my EmailViewModel.  Why is this?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendStudentAnEmail(FormCollection emailFormCollection)
{
        Debug.Write(emailFormCollection["email"]);
        Debug.Write(emailFormCollection["subject"]);
        Debug.Write(emailFormCollection["body"]);
    var email = new EmailViewModel
                        {
                            Email = emailFormCollection["email"],
                            Subject = emailFormCollection["subject"],
                            Body = emailFormCollection["body"]
                        };
. . . . then the rest of my code works just how I wanted. . .
```

Why do I have to cast from FormCollection over to my EmailViewModel?  Why isn't it giving me the NullReference Exception if I attempt to simply push an EmailViewModel into my Action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `EmailViewModel` class has a property called `Email` of type string. And your controller action takes an argument called `email` of type `EmailViewModel`. This confuses the default model binder. So either rename the property inside the view model or the action argument:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendStudentAnEmail(EmailViewModel model)
{
    Debug.Write(model.Subject);
    Debug.Write(model.Body);
    Debug.Write(model.Email);
    ...
}
```